# Send/receive messaages from vuejs frontend to spring boot backend

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

I would like to get a minimal setup with a Vuejs frontend that can send and receive to/from a spring boot backend.

I have managed to build and run the below Vuejs frontend

**FrontEnd:**

https://github.com/nolanlawson/vuejs-hello-world

and this spring boot:

**Backend:**

https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-vuejs/tree/master/backend

On my local machine.

But now I am looking for guidelines on how to get a minimal communication flow up and running so I can easily send some message from my vuejs frontend to the spring boot backend and check the reply.

Any suggestions on how get started with implementing that based on the above two projects?

Comment: Your example backend project doesn't only contain the backend Spring Boot sources, but also the Vue.js frontend code - including the Axios code in https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-vuejs/blob/master/frontend/src/components/backend-api.js and the Spring Boot RestController in https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-vuejs/blob/master/backend/src/main/java/de/jonashackt/springbootvuejs/controller/BackendController.java. The whole meaning of the project was to show the integration of Spring Boot AND Vue.js (note: I'am the author).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down into two steps,

1. **Backend** - Here you want to have an endpoint which receives data as either GET Params or POST body, process it and return a easily parse-able format (like json)
2. **Frontend** - Use an xhr library (like axios) to send a request to that specific endpoint with the data it needs to process, wait for the request to complete, you'll receive the response as a string, parse that json string into a js object and you can then process it.

Resources which will help you get started:

Axios Example: https://github.com/axios/axios#example

Restful Service with spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/